# Ellipse not transparent

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to crop an image (drawing an ellipse on top) and then paste it on another image.

```
bg_img = Image.open('bgimgs/light.png')
bg_img = bg_img.resize((600, 420))


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
image_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()

profile_pic = Image.open(image_file, mode='r')

profile_pic = profile_pic.resize((55, 55))
profile_mask = (55, 55)

mask = Image.new('L', profile_mask, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)

draw.ellipse((0, 0) + profile_mask, fill=255)
mask = mask.resize(profile_pic.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
profile_pic.putalpha(mask)

bg_img.paste(profile_pic, (25, 40))
```

and it produces this.
How can i make the ellipse around picture transparent?

[image]

Comment: This [note.nkmk.me](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-putalpha/) has a good description.

Comment: @Brian thanks. I checked the example and it seems like I'm doing most of it the same just with different way. Tried using the example code and the profile still continues.